# Remove empty tags from XML via XSLT and bubble elements up

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following problem.
I have a xml file like this

```
<p>
    <span class="dateline">City</span><p>
        <p>
            <em>City.</em>some text
        </p>
    </p><p>
        <p/>
    </p>
    [... unknown number of other nested paragraphs with text ...]
</p>
```

and i want it to look like that:

```
<p>
    <span class="dateline">City</span>
    <em>City.</em>some text
</p>
```

So i have to go to every leaf p-tag and take everything in it and move it to the parent p-tag as long as there are parent p-tags.
Afterwards i would remove all empty p-tags.

How can this be done with xslt 1.0?

Comment: Besides manual editing, what have you tried? Please post the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're more likely to get good responses to questions here if you show what you have tried, in a form that allows others to reproduce the problem (this is of course difficult if you have no idea where to start).  Not showing your work gives the impression you haven't done any and just want others to do your work for you.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- This template preserve all elements without template -->   

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<!-- This template remove all elements without childs (you can replace * by p)-->
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]"/>
<!-- This template remove p inside other p but preserve all childs --> 
<xsl:template match="p[parent::p]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write an identity transform (if you don't know what that is, look it up as it's worth learning), and then add two templates for paragraphs:  one with `match="p"` to match `p` elements which are not nested inside other `p` elements, and one with `match="p[ancestor::p]"` to match others.  The first template is just an explicit restatement of the identity template (that is, the template could be omitted without change of functionality; I'd include it only to make the handling of all paragraphs explicit).  The second omits the `xsl:copy` instruction and just applies templates to all children.

Comment: Pedagogically perfect.